# How to fix bug with endless writing of numbers using FileWriter with append argument

Tags: java, animation, event-handling, paintcomponent, filewriter

I faced one problem which I’m struggling to solve.
Imagine simple game, where some object , lets call it car, remains motionless on X-axis ( x = 50 ) and is able to move only on Y-axis (up and down). At the same time, another objects are created beyond the screen at random point ( and move toward my first object ) , so their coordinates decrementing on X-axis. As soon as every object reaches my first object coordinates, some variable **int scores;** increments.

```
int scores;
if(cars.getX() == getCarPos_X() && cars.getY() != getCarPos_Y() )
   scores++;
```

Basically this game looks like car  which goes between other cars and avoid hitting, and counter **scores** increments every time my car pass next moving car.

**So what is the problem?**
I use timer which count time between repainting. All objects pass to the paintComponent where actually all graphic draw. In actionPerformed I call methods for all moves, and one method which checks if collision with another car occurred. In case of collision, game stops, and scores should be written in some txt file. 
The problem is that while two objects have same coordinates, JVM write endless number of figures (**scores**) into the file ( I think it’s because coordinates stop decrementing and every timer interval it checks for collision and it’s == true , as game is stoped , and object remains where they are.) 
So my scores in txt file looks like :

```
0
0
0
0
```

In one column.
Or it displays any score which I’ve got.
And so on...

---

Here is the crucial code snippet which I used

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
  animate();
  checkTouch();
}
private void animate()
{
  //here code that creates obstacles and moves them
}
 checkTouch()
{
  //objects creating in some inner class Cars and add to ArrayList ( I don’t mention about it as it is beside the point )
  for(Cars car : cars)
   {
     if((cars.getX() == getCarPos_X && cars. getY() == getCarPos_Y())
     {
       //boolean var which stops game
       inGame = false;
       writeScore();
     }
   }
}
 public void writeScore()
{
  File scoresTxt = new File("scores.txt");
  FileWriter fw = null;
  BufferedWriter bw = null;
  try
   {
     fw = new FileWriter(scoresTxt, true);
     bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
     bw.write(scores + "\n");
   }catch (IOException e)
    {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }finally
    {
     try
      {
        bw.flush();
        bw.close();
        fw.close();
      }catch(IOException e)
       {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
 if(inGame)
 {
 g.drawImage(myCar, 50, 100, this);

 for(Cars car : cars)
 {
   g.drawImage(obstacleCar, car.getX(), car.getY(), this);
 }
  }
}
```

Should you need some extra code I used, write comment and I’ll add it.
**And again I need to fix bug which write endless column of numbers instead of one final score from the moment of collision.**
What’s wrong with my code , and how to solve this problem?
Give me advice for simplest decision, as I’m beginner.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd write this as an answer, but I can't be sure about it so I won't. Try doing `System.exit(0)`, make a `boolean value GameOver` which is changed after the game over screen only happens once, preventing it from being written ever again, or find a way to stop the `checkTouch()` method from being triggered again. Maybe `timer.stop()` will get the spamming to stop. If you can find that none of these work, tell me.

Comment: @FailingCoder yeah , I stopped timer and it stopped spamming. But I don’t know is it best decision in terms of good programs style?

Answer (score 0):

If your timer is started like this, or something similar, the you could cancel it when the inGame variable becomes false.  [Nice article on timers](https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask).

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (!inGame)
            cancel();
        else
            // whatever it is that you are doing now
    }
};
```

You might also want to stop processing events in the actionPerformed(e) method in a similar way.

```
if (!inGame) 
    return;
```